# Custom Directive inside a Directive using ControllerAs syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I have two directives, one that's a table, and one that's a row. In this case the row is the same each time, and I just want to have it displayed twice in the index.html. `<table-row>` works in the index.html, but `<table>` does not why?

i.e.:

```
.directive('table', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: 'table-ctrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    template:`
      <div>
        <table-row></table-row>
        <table-row></table-row>
      </div>`
  };
});
```

Table Row:

```
.controller('TableRowCtrl', function() {
  this.toggle = function() {
     this.toggleBool = !this.toggleBool;
  }
  //
  this.toggleBool = false;
})

.directive('TableRow', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    controller: 'TableRowCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    template: `
      <div>
        <span>Object</span>
        <span>
          <img ng-click="ctrl.toggle()" src="jpeg file" />
        </span>
        <span ng-if="ctrl.toggleBool"> Print </span>
      </div>`
  };
});
```

If `table-row` is the other directive that does everything and its controller is also what runs on clicks etc, how would I link in the `table-row` directive so that the `table` directive template works, and will call `table-row` multiple times.I would like to continue using the `ControllerAs` syntax instead of `$scope`.

Comment: Please read this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive clearly

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you want to use `controllerAs` or not. From your code `table` directive has isolate scope and suppose if you want to iterate through `table-row` items by using `ngRepeat` directive it should be isolate scope as well.

Remember that every `ngRepeat`'s item has own scope

For example:

```
.directive('table', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: 'table-ctrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    template:
      <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
        <table-row item="item"></table-row>        
      </div>`
  };
});
```

Comment: You should have explain clearly the directives that can communicate

Comment: So in this case, <table-row>is supposed to be the same thing each time, and I just want to try printing it twice. But when I got to run the index.html with <table> it doesn't work, but if i use <table-row> it does work.

Comment: @user3628240 You can create hundreds of `<table-row>` items and each item will have scope by his own.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to angular, but the 'table' directive should generate a <table> element that should just contain 2 <table-row> elements, but when I call <table></table> in index.html it won't display the <table-row> elements. In my actual code the <table> directive is changed, since it's an html native element.

Comment: @user3628240 post your `<table-row>` directive. Check HTML that you don't have css issues

Comment: Ok, i added in the `<table-row>` directive